# Converting OpenStreetMap into tcl file using SUMO

Tags: tcl, openstreetmap, ns2, sumo, ad-hoc-network

Here is the error I got after running uttara.tcl which created from a sumo file:

```
~/vanet$ ns uttara.tcl  
num_nodes is set 47

warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl

INITIALIZE THE LIST 
xListHead
Starting Simulation...

ns: _o14 setdest 1774.28 2170.28 0.00: 
    (_o14 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o14 cmd setdest 1774.28 2170.28 0.00"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o14" line 2)
(SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o14 setdest 1774.28 2170.28 0.00"
```

I have attached the mobility.tcl and uttara.tcl file also [link of tcl files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yjsf9x4ExfzjbEEiv3f2CD_5WIcpVyBw)

Answer (score 0):

uttara.tcl : Extend the X Y range →

```
set opt(x) 3000
set opt(y) 2500
```

mobility.tcl : Edit negative settings (-0.31, -0.32) in lines 26704, 33758 to a positive number →

```
.
$ns_ at 82.1 "$node_(5) setdest 1648.22 2.00 27.69"
.
.
$ns_ at 98.8 "$node_(6) setdest 1648.22 1.00 27.75"
```

---

My test: `$ ns235-64-orig uttara-2.tcl` : The files uttara.nam 3.8MB, uttara.tr 3.1MB are created. `$ nam uttara.nam` : A perfect animation.

Link to the edited files https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gsA3XFMHGyz1ca4fDkxJQTzou6l7p6zr/view?usp=sharing

Okt 2021 update: Vanet-examples-Aug21.tar.xz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qXG-HWykHc-_60BezCsbGifEFx2mlETs/view?usp=sharing
... **and** → https://neo.lcc.uma.es/staff/jamal/vanet/index.html%3Fq=node%252F11.html